# Python : checking if all letters in two words are exactly the same but not in same order (amphisbaena)

Tags: python

A word is an amphisbaena if the first half and the last half of the word contain exactly the same letters, but not necessarily in the same order. In case the word has an odd number of letters, the middle letter is ignored in this definition (or it belongs to both halves).

My code works in most cases except for example with: 'eisegesis' -> eise esis 
My code doesn't check if all letters appear ONLY ONE TIME UNIQUE in the other word and vice versa. The letter 's' doesn't appear two times in the other part (half) of the word. How can I adjust my code?

```
def amphisbaena(word):

    """ 
    >>> amphisbaena('RESTAURATEURS')
    True
    >>> amphisbaena('eisegesis')
    False
    >>> amphisbaena('recherche')
    True
    """


    j = int(len(word) / 2)


    count = 0
    tel = 0

    firstpart, secondpart = word[:j], word[-j:]
    for i in firstpart.lower():
        if i in secondpart.lower():
            count +=1
    for i in secondpart.lower():
        if i in firstpart.lower():
            tel +=1
    if 2 * j == count + tel:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: It looks like you want to check whether the first and last halves of the word are anagrams of one another, in which case `sorted` will probably help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to count letters in both halves separately and compare counts for each letter. Simplest is to use a `collections.Counter`:

```
def amphisbaena(word):
    from collections import Counter
    w = word.lower()
    half = len(word) // 2
    return half == 0 or Counter(word[:half]) == Counter(word[-half:])
```

While this is not quite as simple as just comparing the sorted halves, it is `O(N)` as opposed to `O(N * log_N)`.

Answer (score 3):

i would have done something like this:

```
j = int(len(word) / 2)

firstpart, secondpart = word[:j], word[-j:]
return sorted(firstpart) == sorted(secondpart)
```

Comment: Why not `return sorted(firstpart) == sorted(secondpart)`? `None` is false-y, so the behaviour is still approximately correct, but it seems a bit weird.

Comment: For `word = 'a'` you return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with lambda  function in one line :

```
   string_1='recherche'

    half=int(len(string_1)/2)

    amphisbaena=lambda x: True if sorted(x[:half])==sorted(x[-half:]) else False
    print(amphisbaena(string_1))
```

output:

```
True
```

With other string :

```
string_1='eisegesis'

half=int(len(string_1)/2)

amphisbaena=lambda x: True if sorted(x[:half])==sorted(x[-half:]) else False
print(amphisbaena(string_1))
```

output:

```
False
```